# Which Midori to download?

Tags: web-browsers

Trivial question, but I am uncertain. I have a Raspberry Pi running NOOB, and I was curious as to **(Q:)** which Midori to [download](http://midori-browser.org/download/)? I've looked across the internet couldn't find it. The current browser is epiphany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on Raspbian,  you can do:

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install midori
```

this will install the latest version available from the repo.

Comment: thanks mate! But I have a [small problem](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29254/trouble-auto-refreshing-a-website) with Midori... and was hoping if you could give me any advice?

Comment: What exactly is the problem because the best way to install it is through apt-get.?